# How does varchar2 sorting in oracle works?

Tags: oracle, varchar2

I'm sorting a Oracle SQL query by a Varchar2 column. But when I get the results i can not correctly understand the ordering. Which is the logical order. first lower letters? numbers? symbols?. Here I attach the resulting ordering of one of the tests:

```
select FieldToOrder from MyTable order by FieldToOrder ASC
```

being `FieldToOrder` a VARCHAR2 column

---

**FieldToOrder:**

" 77777777777" //The first character is a blank space

"aaas"

"_aad"

"AADD"

"A00004AAAA9999"

"ref11"

"ref22"

"0000000002222"

---

Any ideas of what's the logical order? Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the environment variable `NLS_LANG` on your client side. See [this reference on `NLS_SORT`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm).

Comment: By default it uses binary representation for sorting, it can be changed to linguistic and  customized for monolanguage or multilanguage . More info:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch5lingsort.htm#insertedID0